# Properties of conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I knew that $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B|C)=\mathbb{P}(A|C)\cdot \mathbb{P}(B|C)$. However I found (pg. 52, cap II - Dall'Aglio Giorgio, Calcolo delle probabilità) that $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B|C)=\mathbb{P}(A|B)\cdot \mathbb{P}(B|C)$.

What is the difference between these two properties? When should I use the first and when the second?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The first one is only true if $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: @Paul Perfect, thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @Paul: To be precise, the first one is only true if $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent, conditional on $C$.

Comment: The second of these is not true in general either.  Either there's a typo in the equation, or the statement of some special condition under which it would be true has been omitted.  In general, it is true that
$$
\frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B|C)}{\mathbb{P}(B|C)}= \mathbb{P}(A| B\cap C)\ ,
$$
so the given equation would be true if and only if
$$
\mathbb{P}(A| B\cap C)= \mathbb{P}(A| B)\ .
$$